# How to declare same variable in both super class and subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, java-11

**Parent class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseChapter {
  protected String chapterId;
  private List<BaseSection> sections;
}
```

**Child class **

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Chapter extends BaseChapter {
  private Integer title;
 private List<Section> sections; 
}
```

I'm using springboot and java 11 ,I need to use sections variable in both baseChapter and Chapter class
I use both classes in two diffrent APIs.but i got error when doing this.how to overcome this problem

Comment: What error? Also explain why do you want to do that, sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: There is no problem in declaring these variables. Remove the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations or don’t use the compiler hack that gives them a meaning and you’ll see that the code compiles without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the problem is, you want to override the type of this list, not have two different lists.

In that case I would propose to use generics:

superclass

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseChapter <T extends BaseChapter> {
  protected String chapterId;
  private List<T> sections;
}
```

subclass

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Chapter extends BaseChapter<Chapter> {
  private Integer title;
}
```